Some questions about tags
I have a couple of questions about tags:

I've seen a tag called "composites." Shouldn't it be "compounds"?
If we think that it's better to have two tags, "word-meaning" for the meaning of single words and "meaning" for expressions or phrases, shouldn't it be the same with tags "usage" and "word-usage"? (at the moment the "usage" has been defined as a synonym of "word-usage")


I edited composites into compounds
